# OpenGL Правомерность действия

Tags: opengl, матрицы, transform

В ходе моего обучения OpenGL у меня возник вопрос.
Я получаю с камеры видео поток используя `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES`.
Далее для правильной выборки из текстуры (нужно перевести "стандартные" st координаты в координаты текстуры) я использую трюк:

```
  glm::mat4 st {
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 0, 0
   };

 compensate_matrix = st * glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::radians(180.0f), glm::vec3(0,0,1));
```

Далее в шейдере:

```
var_st = (compensate_matrix * vec4(st.x, st.y, 0, 1.0)).xy;
```

Собственно вопрос, насколько правомерно выражение, и что оно значит:

```
... st * glm::rotate ...?
```

Comment: А вы его уберите и посмотрите, что получится. Картинка перевернется и сдвинется.

Comment: Непонятно что вас смущает. Вопрос о том насколько правомерно перемножать матрицы??